# How to customize BartPE for Unattended operation?

Tags: unattended, bartpe

Wondering if it's possible to customize BartPE for unattended operation. I would like to boot BartPE through network(PXE) to headless PC, where it should do some operations and reboot PC. For that I need to write script somewhere, I guess autoexec.bat?

- Which plugins I need for writing autorun script?
- Can I silently install network driver/how?

Comment: BartPE (last release in 2006) is obsolete unless you're running this on older, XP-compatible hardware.  You should look into WinPE instead from Microsoft's WAIK kit instead.

Comment: XP compatible hardware is what I am looking for.